# Bootstrap row aligned too high

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, row

I have been trying this problem for quite a while but I haven't found a solution yet.
I have build this site with Bootstrap including two containers. Something is going wrong for the last row in the last container (it has #bottombar). For some reason it is aligned on top of the parent row. Any help would be appreciated!

http://www.dutchcorporatebusinesssolutions.com/Tax-and-Financial

Comment: please post code and preferably a JSFiddle or something like it

Answer (score 1):

In your stylesheet you have the tablecontent class, which sets the height of tablecontent to 150px. That will make the bottombar appear 150px below the title. Remove the

```
 height: 150px;
```

from your .tablecontent CSS class and you should be fine.